# Can't get toast to work in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-places-api, toast, android-toast

I cannot get a toast to display in a fragment. I am using the PlacePicker, the user selects a place and the toast is supposed to show the place they selected. I have tried `getContext()`, `getActivity().getApplicationContext()` & `getActivity()` but none are working.

The PlacePicker is loading fine it just wont display the toast. I would also like to display the place the user has chosen in a TextView but the toast is the main priority.

My code is below:

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {

int PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST = 1;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
    try {
        startActivityForResult(builder.build(getActivity()), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, getActivity());
            String toastMsg = String.format("Place: %s", place.getName());
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), toastMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `getActivity().startActivityForResult(...);` - Do not call that on the `Activity`. Just call it directly; i.e., remove `getActivity().` from that line - `startActivityForResult(...);`.

Comment: That fixed it, thanks. Do you know if there is a way to launch the place picker when the fragment is loaded instead of loading the place picker with a button and using the `onClick` method?

Comment: You can move that code - minus the `Button` stuff - to `onActivityCreated()`.

Comment: I have updated the code above to show what I have now. I have moved this to the `onActivityCreated()` but it still isn't appearing. Do I need to put something in the XML too?

Comment: Please don't change the actual question like that. It's fine that you asked a simple follow up in comments, but now this isn't what you originally asked. Anyway, I said `onActivityCreated()`, not `onActivityResult()`.

Comment: Ok thanks. I am new to stackoverflow and still trying to get used to the rules and ways of doing things. I will ask a new question in future if it is different to the original question.